# I write this query in my query in Mysql but it not work in Hive. It's Show me an error

Tags: mysql, hive

```
select c.customer_id,concat(c.customer_fname,' ',c.customer_lname) as fullname, o.order_customer_id,o.order_status from 
customers c left outer join orders o on (c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id) 
group by o.order_status
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is

Comment: Add more details to your question.

Comment: You have done group by on order_status, whereas in select clause you have non group by columns --> customer_id, full_name, order_customer_id, Provide sample data to help you with the right query

Comment: All non-aggregated columns appearing in the SELECT list should be functionally dependent on the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
select 
 c.customer_id,
 concat(c.customer_fname,' ',c.customer_lname) as fullname,
 o.order_customer_id,
 o.order_status 
from 
 customers c left outer join orders o on (c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id) 
 group by c.customer_id,concat(c.customer_fname,' ',c.customer_lname),o.order_customer_id, o.order_status
```

As other stackies already suggested you were missing columns in your `group by` statement. All non aggregated columns should be included in `group by`.